# Pandas calculation inconsistencies

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

The question I'm going to ask might be a bit weird. 
I'm using recent Anaconda 3.5 distribution to perform calculations.
All my routines are mostly based on numpy and pandas.

Recently, I discovered a **very strange behavior of Pandas/numpy/python** (don't know who's responsible).

Suppose I have a 2 col (`G, B`) Pandas DataFrame without index (integer index) denoted by `l` and the following function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def runTest(l):
    res = l.G  + 1j * l.B
    return res
```

Both columns have `float64` dtype. So, I'm trying to create a complex number where the real part is taken from `G` and imaginary from `B`.

**The weird thing is:** if we ran this code, let's say, for a few hundreds of times, some outcomes might be **drastically different** from what normally comes out.

*An example on my data:*

```
def printDifference(y1, y2):
    dif = np.absolute(y1 - y2) > 1e-13
    ys1 = y1[dif]
    ys2 = y2[dif]
    for i in range(ys1.shape[0]):
        print("{:d}: {:f} vs {:f}".format(i, ys1.iloc[i], ys2.iloc[i]))

main = runTest(l)
for i in range(200):
    test = runTest(l)
    if np.any(np.absolute(main - test) > 1e-10):
        print(i)
        printDifference(main, test)
        break
```

> 149
>
> 0: 0.000000+0.000093j vs 0.000000+0.000000j
>
> 1: 0.000003+0.000132j vs 0.000006+0.000132j
>
> 2: 0.000000+0.000006j vs 0.000000+0.000006j
>
> 3: 0.000002+0.000113j vs 0.000005+0.000113j
>
> 4: 0.000000+0.000009j vs 0.000000+0.000009j
>
> 5: 0.000005+0.000210j vs 0.000009+0.000210j
>
> 6: 0.000004+0.000161j vs 0.000007+0.000161j
>
> 7: 0.000004+0.000160j vs 0.000007+0.000160j
>
> 8: 0.000002+0.000095j vs 0.000004+0.000095j
>
> 9: 0.000011+0.000448j vs 0.000022+0.000448j
>
> ....

1. Note, that it happened only on **149**th iteration.
2. It looks like real part is accounted twice, but also somewhere the imaginary part is different.
3. If i change `1j * l.B` to `1j * l.B.values` everything (statistically) becomes normal.

**The question is:** what is going on??? I read both Pandas and Numpy docs on calculations but hadn't found a thing that might explain this behavior.

Any guess would be highly appreciated!

**P.s.** I could provide the exact data if there's a need in it. But I'm not sure what type of conainer I should use, so put the request, I'll handle.

---

**upd**
I successfully reproduced the error for
`l = pd.DataFrame({'G': np.random.rand(14000) * 1e-7, 'B': np.random.rand(14000) * 1e-5})`

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with different data?

Comment: I haven't tried. You mean some random float data? I'll try

Comment: Yep. That's  what I meant. I used `l = ps.DataFrame({'G': np.random.rand(100) * 1e-5, 'B': np.random.rand(100) * 1e-5})` and the result is consistent.

Comment: It's good also to set seed in this case, eg `np.random.seed(123)` so everyone produces same random numbers

Comment: reproduced for `l = pd.DataFrame({'G': np.random.rand(14000) * 1e-7, 'B': np.random.rand(14000) * 1e-5})` (I mean I got the same thing as above)

Comment: Something is not right, here. Either your system/Python installation is broken or you did not show all the relevant code. Can you create a minimal self-contained example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Sure. If you combine the `l` initialization that I posted, and both blocks of code in the body of question - it reproduces the problem on my machine. Meanwhile, I'll check it on other systems and post an update if I get something interesting.

Comment: BTW, with your variant of `l` there were no problems

Comment: @kazemakase Tested the code on OS X 10.11.4 with Python 3.5.1-0 and... alas. Could not reproduce, even with the original data. So, what do you suggest to do? Check the installation? Update packages? Originally I did it on Windows machine (2012 r2 server).

Comment: Try to reinstall everything (pandas, numpy, python, even anaconda?). I don't know what else could solve the issue or cause...

Comment: @kazemakase Well, it seems like the following procedures somehow resolved the problem:  
- total uninstallation of all python environments and distributions  
- fresh install of Anaconda (windows, so scipy won't install so easily)  
- `conda install pandas` to fetch 0.18 update  
I'm currently running more precise tests to clarify if it's finally gone, but the example above is now works perfectly fine

Comment: This was very likely the result of having numexpr 2.4.4 installed, which is known to be flaky.  If you reinstalled, you probably upgraded numexpr to >= 2.5, which doesn't have the problem.  The problem also only shows up on windows, which makes it even more annoying.

Comment: @DSM Wow, thanks! This is something specific. Do you mind adding a full reply?

Comment: @ghastly_kitten: instead I'll just close it as a dup of an earlier question.  We've now blacklisted 2.4.4 (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12489)).